# How to pass data to onkeyup event

Tags: lightning-aura-components

I am trying to pass data from my inputfield to my onkeyup event, but it doesn't work.

I have a simple field:

```
<lightning:inputField fieldName="Name" onkeyup="{! c.onmouseup}" data-tab="information"/>
```

I have a simple handler:

```
onmouseup : function(component, event, helper) {
    var ctarget = event.currentTarget;
    var tab = ctarget.dataset.tab;
    alert(tab);
},
```

It say ctarget is null, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: I don't think that syntax is supported in Aura - https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/lightning_base_events.htm You'll need to user event.getSource()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the model I've found to work:

```
onmouseup : function(cmp, event, helper) {
  let tab = event.currentTarget.getAttribute('data-tab');
  alert(tab);
},
```

Comment: I worked around the problem by not passing value and redesign the system but I'll mark this answer as correct for others.

Comment: Sounds great, thanks!